# undefined method `to_json' for #<Hash:0x3d3cef0> (NoMethodError) in ActiveSupport 3

Tags: ruby, activesupport

Did to_json get removed or something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try adding `require "active_support/core_ext"`

`require 'active_support'` doesn't inject behavior into the core classes by itself. That way you can pick which extensions you want. Using `core_ext` dumps the extensions you are familiar with from rails into the core classes.

Comment: Ahhh, shoulda known this, similar thing happened recently. This is new in 3.0 though right? This stuff used to work without doing this.

Comment: I think it was in one of the 2.3.x releases. I saw this behavior with 2.3.9